# Server Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, runtime-error

I'm getting an error from an Action Method, but the Wcf called by the Action method successfully works.

This is the code:

## MVC Action

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveFee(FeeViewModel feeViewModel)
{           
    var response = new AjaxResponse();

    try{
        Fee feeToSave = new Fee()
        {
            Id = feeViewModel.Id,
            Amount = feeViewModel.Amount
        };

        var a = FeeService.Instance.GetService().InsertFee(feeToSave);

        response.Success = true;
        response.ResponseData = a.ResponseData;
        return Json(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.Success = false;
        response.ErrorMessage = ex?.Message;
        return Json(response);
    }
}
```

## WCF

```
public class BlFee : IFee
{
    public WcfResponse InsertFee(Fee myFee)
    {
        WcfResponse response = new WcfResponse();

        try
        {
            using (ModelEntity dbContext = new ModelEntity())
            {
                dbContext.Add(myFee);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }

            response.Success = true;
            response.ResponseData = myFee;
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Success = false;
            response.ErrorMessage = "Generic Error occurred during the fee saving";
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

As said, the Wcf works fine,because it saves the record on the table on the db, but when it comes back to the action it catches an Exception( of type "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException"), so configured:

> **className:**
>   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException
>
> **ex.InnerException.Message:**
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
>
> **ex._message:**
>   An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:49730/MyService.svc/IFeeService. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.
>
> **ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message:**
>   Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>
> **ex.InnerException:**
>   The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
>
> **InternalStatus:**
>   RequestFatal

Can you help please?

Comment: I tried to reword the question, trying to be more specific and focused on the problem. Can you reopen it please?

Comment: Got the same error. Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Unluckily I don't remember Dominic, it's been too long, I'm sorry

Comment: I have found the answer for my problem. If you have a `ReadOnly` Property, make a `protected setter` and everything is fine.

Comment: nice to know, thanks for sharing Dominic